# Tensorflow input pipeline with text file

Tags: tensorflow

```
def read_file(input_file_name, output_file_name):
     input_reader = open(input_file_name)
     output_reader = open(output_file_name)
     return input_reader.readline(), output_reader.readline()

def make_batch(batch_size)
     #(['My','Name'],['Amily'])
     input_, output_ = read_file(inp_file_name, oup_file_name)

     #([0 3], [14])
     input_idx, output_idx = str_to_index(input_, output_)

     # WHAT SHOULD I DO!!!!! I want to use tf.train.batch()
     return batch_input, batch_output
```

I have no idea for making input queue with string.......
How can I make it!?

Comment: You should probably use [tf.data.TextLineDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_text_data) instead of queues. Then you can write your own map() method to apply to the dataset for preprocessing.

Sorry I don't have time to show a working code. But you can take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/DongjunLee/text-cnn-tensorflow/), especially the data_loader.py class.

Comment: @yiping Thanks a lot :) It's really helpful answer!!!!!